# Display on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm struggling to get the following code working. Basically I'm trying to get `.cbp-fbscroller` in my css to make my new navigation menu on the side in the html page only appear at 900px on scroll down, but being new to JavaScript I don't know how to get the code working.

So once it reaches 900px the navigation on the side will appear. I have made a fiddle so you guys can see more of the code

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vLf18Lbk/35/)

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 100) {
        if ($(".main").css('display') === 'none') {
            $(".cbp-fbscroller").fadeIn('slow');
            $(".main").prev().fadeOut();
            $(".cbp-fbscroller").next().fadeOut();
        }
    } else {
        /* if ($(".main").css('display') !== 'none') {
            $(".cbp-fbscroller").fadeOut('slow');
            $(".main").prev().fadeIn();
            $(".cbp-fbscroller").next().fadeIn();
        } */
    }
})
```

Comment: FYI: Don't use centered text on a webpage for continous text. The eye has to search for the beginning of each new line again, which is bad user experience.

Comment: would you say align-left is more suitable? :)

Comment: Your jsFiddle is just a code dump, and your in-question example is not complete enough to determine what the issue is. Please [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And please make sure it is **Minimal**, **Complete** and **Verifiable**.

Comment: fiddle has been reduced to the thing needing to be changed :)

Comment: Yep, definitely align-left.

Comment: Your MCVE is not in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understod your question, basicly you need this:

```
$(function() {

  $(window).on('scroll', function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 900) {
       $('.cbp-fbscroller nav').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
       $('.cbp-fbscroller nav').fadeOut('slow');
    }

  });

});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6oaxt61a/10/

and a change in your HTML

```
<nav>
```

to

```
<nav style="display:none;">
```

Comment: No the side navigation is still present here. Basically if the browser is at the top it must be hidden, and once it scrolls to about 800px it must appear so the user can navigate

Comment: look at the fiddle, there is one initial `style="display:none"`  in `<nav>` tag - the navigation should be hidden on load. test the fidle please

Comment: loaded the fiddle. still seems to be there on load

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6oaxt61a/10/ - sorry - that's the fiddle - you need to just change  `<nav>` to `<nav style="display:none;">`

Comment: sweet will giv it a go :)

Comment: you are a champion man. Just need to figure out with my html why it isnt appearing on top but ill hav a look around :P thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you are trying to do correctly, your code should be looking something like this:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 100) {
        if ($(".main").css('display') === 'none') {
            $(".cbp-fbscroller").fadeIn('slow');
            $(".main").prev().fadeOut();
            $(".cbp-fbscroller").next().fadeOut();
        }
    } else {
        /* if ($(".main").css('display') !== 'none') {
            $(".cbp-fbscroller").fadeOut('slow');
            $(".main").prev().fadeIn();
            $(".cbp-fbscroller").next().fadeIn();
        } */
    }
})
```

The part I comment out is just incase you want to revert the action.

What you are lacking:

1. No event attached. That was fixed by `$(document).scroll(function(){...`
2. `'"foobar"'` will only raise an error. use either `'foo'` or `"bar"`

Hope I interpret you correctly.

Comment: I updated the fiddle. You are very close to getting what im asking, just needs to be the opposite. As it needs to scroll 800px and then appear, and if there are only >800 then it needs to dissapear